# How to catch the dynamic part of the URL in react router

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this route which calls `PriceWithId` function

```js
<Route path='/collections/:pId' component={PriceWithID} />
```

The function is like this

```js
const PriceWithID = ({match}) =>
    {
        let test = Object.entries(match);
        let test2 = test.filter(([prop])=>(prop === 'params'));
        let test3 = test2[0][1];
        let test4 = Object.values(test3)[0]
        return(
          <Price image={IMGS.filter((i)=>(i.id === parseInt(test4,10)))[0]}/>
        );
    }
```

I know there is a **nicer oneline way** to achieve `test4`. The method I used came with trial and error. Can anyone **tell me the nicer way so that I can replace test4 in parseInt with it**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `this.props.match.params.pId`

or with functional component

```
const PriceWithID = (props) =>
    {
        let pId = props.match.params.pId
        return(
          <Price image={IMGS.filter((i)=>(i.id === parseInt(pId))[0]}/>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Burning Alcohol

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer can be improved upon this way:

```js
const PriceWithID = ({match}) =>
    {
        return(
          <Price image={IMGS.filter((i)=>(i.id === parseInt(match.params.pId,10)))[0]}/>
        );
    }
```

But as the previous solution was correct I marked it as answer.